# Does the Community background process randomly mark questions as Community Wiki?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki, community-user

I recently noticed that one of my [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/93105/list) was marked as Community Wiki by the Community background process even though it hasn't met any of the criteria for "wikification":

- The body of the post has been edited by four different people.
- The post has been edited six times by the original owner.
- The question generates more than 30 answers. In this case, the question and all answers will enter community mode, as will any future answers.

None of these are true, but it was still marked as Community Wiki by the Community process.  Why?

Edit: No, a moderator did not do it:

[alt text http://img183.imageshack.us/img183/5161/20090915145822.png](http://img183.imageshack.us/img183/5161/20090915145822.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "randomly" to community wiki.

Prior to about 2 months ago, the user was not stored / shown in the switch to community wiki.

This post was made community wiki Jan 9 which predates that change. Thus, it could have been any user.

My guess is, at some point, someone edited the question and ticked "community wiki" as their only change. Why, I have no idea; maybe it was accidental.

Answer (score 0):

A moderator probably changed it to Community Wiki.

Basically anything that happens on the site that shouldn't be associated with a real user, gets "owned" by the Community User.

---

The code has been changed since January, when that question was changed Community Wiki. The revision list will now list who made it Community Wiki, if it was done by a moderator.

Comment: It may have changed recently for it to show the moderator as the one changing it to CW. If you note, the question listed was Wikified in January.

Comment: Just to clear up disinformation, when moderators use "force to wiki" it **DOES** store the user who performed the operation in the revision history.

Answer (score -1):

It's a *Best way* question: Doomed!

Comment: So that process analyzes the text of questions and CWs those that ask for the "best way"?

Comment: Bet on it! I would do it that way. But I haven't seen the code.